# fill at once data null on table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

I have table `transaksi`:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and have data (I fill in the data with insert into transaksi (name,price,type) select name,price,type from store)

```
+-----------+--------------------------+---------+-------+
| id        | name                     | price   | Type  |
+-----------+--------------------------+---------+-------+
|      NULL | Pants                    |  79     |     9 |
|      NULL | Cup                      |  38     |     7 |
|      NULL | Shoes                    |  21     |     1 |
|      NULL | Hat                      |  11     |     5 |
|      NULL | Pulpen                   |  39     |     2 |
+___________|__________________________|_________|_______|
```

How to fill "NULL" data at once in ID ?

Comment: 'How to fill "NULL" data at once in ID' - with what?

Comment: You want to set every IDs to `NULL` or replace the existing `NULL` values by something else?

Comment: I want to fill in the data in the ID column so that it is not null

Comment: i filll data null by insert transaksi (name,price,type) select name,price,type from store

Comment: and now I want to fill in the NULL data in ID

Comment: I suggest you to let MySQL filling the id field for you, by setting it as `PRIMARY KEY` and using `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Trivial `UPDATE transaksi SET id=0;` will perform needed action formally.. but this is not one you need in, is it?

Comment: I have added PK and AI with transaction ALTER TABLE ........ but it failed

Comment: Can't comment on something we cannot see - add your full alter statement and error message.

Comment: alter table transaksi CHANGE id id  int(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ;
ERROR 1062 (23000): ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Did you follow @akina comment? if not how did id acquire values of 0?

Comment: If you want to ALTER the column and make it PK/AI then you must PREVIOUSLY fill it with NOT NULL unique values. Drop this column and re-create it as AI/PK instead.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue either locally or https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mgrY4ctyQ7jLuFP1Dj5gh4/0.  what version of mysql are you on? I suggest you write the data to a copy of the table with an auto_increment primary key , delete the original table and rename the new table.